# Rank mongodb collection items based on ids in another collection

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections in MongoDB

Collection B includes a manual link to an item in collection A eg:

A
    { _id: 1234 }
B
    { a_id: 1234 }

I want to retrieve a rank of A items based on how many B items link to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the aggregation framework might be your answer. A query like this should do it

```
db.B.aggregate(
    [
        {$group : {"_id" : "$a_id", "a_count" : {"$sum" : 1}}},  
        {$sort : {"a_count" : -1} }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Great! Would it be recommended that you would manually resolve the _ids from the result or could this be handled internally?

Comment: Do you mean fetching the A documents for every a_id ? There is no support for joins. If you need them together, maybe you could embed A in B, or duplicate the fields from A that you need in B

Comment: It just occurred to me that what you describe in your question sounds like a job for a search engine.